# How to connect Elasticsearch to Kafka?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, connector, confluent-platform

I am new in Kafka and elasticSearch,

i want to push data of Elasticsearch to kafka topic, with a connector (source)

I see for kafka to elasticsearch but me i want elasticsearch to kafka

I make this connector with logstash but it's not really what I want, i want kafka listen elasticsearch et pull in topic all the changes of the base.

I have found a plugin jar for confluent-connector

[here][1]

but i have error is not work

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"bkQiBFqdQL-hCbWApo6bBQ","index":"metric"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"metric","node":"wMGlz0c9Q5yViW0bsKhKOA","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"bkQiBFqdQL-hCbWApo6bBQ","index":"metric"}}]},"status":400}
            at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:357)
            at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:346)
            at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:177)
            at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:432)
            at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:325)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:267)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:116)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:339)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:317)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:278)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:590)
            ... 1 more
```

connector use this config

```
{       "name": "elastic-source",
"config": {"connector.class":"com.github.dariobalinzo.ElasticSourceConnector",
                            "tasks.max": "1",
                            "es.host" : "localhost",
                            "es.port" : "9200",
                            "index.prefix" : "metric",
                            "topic.prefix" : "es_",
                            "incrementing.field.name" : "@timestamp"
    }
```

}

this is exemple of data import in my index

```
{"index":{"_index": "movies","_type":"movie","_id":1}}
{"fields" : {"directors" : ["Joseph Gordon-Levitt"],"release_date" : "2013-01-18T00:00:00Z","rating" : 7.4,"genres" : ["Comedy","Drama"],"image_url" : "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQxNTc3NDM2MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzQ5NTQ3OQ@@._V1_SX400_.jpg","plot" : "A New Jersey guy dedicated to his family, friends, and church, develops unrealistic expectations from watching porn and works to find happiness and intimacy with his potential true love.","title" : "Don Jon","rank" : 1,"running_time_secs" : 5400,"actors" : ["Joseph Gordon-Levitt","Scarlett Johansson","Julianne Moore"],"year" : 2013},"id" : "tt2229499","type" : "add"}
```

Thanks you for you help ! :)

EDIT

I change my index with this data

```
    {"index":{"_index": "test","_type":"test","_id":1}}
{"fields" : {"directors" : "Joseph Gordon-Levitt","release_date" : "2013-01-18T00:00:00Z"}}
```

and this config

```
{       "name": "elastic-source",
    "config": {"connector.class":"com.github.dariobalinzo.ElasticSourceConnector",
                                "tasks.max": "1",
                                "es.host" : "localhost",
                                "es.port" : "9200",
                                "index.prefix" : "test",
                                "topic.prefix" : "es_",
                                "incrementing.field.name" : "_score"
        }
}
```

and now i have this error

```
[2018-09-28 11:00:06,367] INFO index test-elasticsearch-sink total messages: null  (com.github.dariobalinzo.task.ElasticSourceTask:149)
[2018-09-28 11:00:06,367] INFO fetching from test (com.github.dariobalinzo.task.ElasticSourceTask:143)
[2018-09-28 11:00:06,373] INFO total shard 5, successuful: 5 (com.github.dariobalinzo.task.ElasticSourceTask:200)
[2018-09-28 11:00:06,373] ERROR error fetching min value (com.github.dariobalinzo.task.ElasticSourceTask:220)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.github.dariobalinzo.task.ElasticSourceTask.fetchLastOffset(ElasticSourceTask.java:215)
        at com.github.dariobalinzo.task.ElasticSourceTask.lambda$poll$0(ElasticSourceTask.java:144)
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
        at com.github.dariobalinzo.task.ElasticSourceTask.poll(ElasticSourceTask.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:244)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:220)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Do you have a idea ? THanks you !!

```
  [1]: https://medium.com/@dariobalinzo/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-source-connector-1a8c16a0e8eb
```

Comment: Please share your error message and the code resulting in the error.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please post exact details of the error you got and what versions of Apache Kafka you're running, how it's installed (docker or not, etc)

Comment: Also : getting data *from* Elasticsearch *into* Kafka is not a common route. Typically if you have an application writing to Elasticsearch, you would get it to write its data to Kafka, and then Kafka to Elasticsearch. The reason being, you then have the data in Kafka to use elsewhere. And as you've found, getting data out of Elasticsearch into Kafka is not so straightforward.

Comment: I have edit  post :)

Comment: The rrror you are getting in Kafka connect is because it is looking for a field @timestamp (incrementing.field.name) which you do not have in your index. I will suggest you to add sample documents available in your index to this question to help use better understand your data.

Comment: I have edit post c:

Comment: So what is the solution?